# Holding a selected file for further use

Tags: c#

I am in a C# Windows Desktop App and I want to know how I can hold a file, as seen whenever you select a file for upload. I am able to open a file for selection, but when I "open" a file, nothing happens. 
This is what I have for my button:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fileContent = string.Empty;
    var filePath = string.Empty;
    using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Get the path of specified file
            filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

            //Read the contents of the file into a stream
            var fileStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }                    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code there will read the bytes of the file. You want to launch the file within the associated application?

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean by "hold a file".

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not clear at all what you mean by "hold a file". Please be more specific. Explain _exactly_ and in detail what the difference between "holding a file" and "not holding a file" would be. What specific effect are you trying to achieve by "holding a file"? What have you tried already to achieve this goal? What _specifically_ are you having trouble figuring out?

Comment: The code reads file contents in `fileContent`. What's issue you are facing here?

Comment: I am not looking to read the file, I plan to convert a selected file into another format, so how I can have my program convert the file that is opened by the user. For example, if you find an online converter or something, it asks you to select a file, and then you hit convert. I am trying to do the "select a file" bit.

Comment: You already did the *select a file* part. Why don't you simply pass the `openFileDialog.FileName` to the method that should perform the *conversion*? (Add `CheckFileExists` to the OFD initialization).

Comment: That could work. How would I do that exactly?

Comment: Would it be this?:

Comment: 'filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
                    var result = Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, ".csv");

                    //Read the contents of the file into a stream
                    var fileStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();'

Comment: If it helps i'm trying to convert a .ics file into a csv for Excel

Comment: FIXED IT! Simple fix. I'll probably ask more questions on how to format in seperators. But until then, thanks!